# Get media likes with real-time photo updates API

Tags: api, instagram, real-time, subscription, social-media-like

With the real-time photos update (https://instagram.com/developer/realtime/) it's possible to have some push updates when a media is created, or when a media with a specific tag is posted, etc.

Is there a way to get an update when someone likes a media?
I didn't find anything, I tried to subscribe to different objects, but the callback is never called when I do a like action.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the four real-time subscriptions available, there is nothing available for subscribing to Likes:

> - Users: receive notifications when users who have registered with your application post new photos.
> - Tags: receive notifications when a new photo is tagged with tags of your choosing
> - Locations: receive notifications when new photos are posted and tagged with a specific location
> - Geographies: receive notifications when a new photos are posted in an arbitrary geographical location as defined by a center point and radius